# Receiving 415 Unsupported Media Type for a multipartfile request

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf

I want to write an API using javax and spring framework(not spring boot) which is supposed to take a post request and upload file to the server where the controller is running in tomcat server. The problem is I've all required code but when I call the API I get 415 unsupported type error. Required code defined as follows:

```
@POST
@Path("file/{productName}")
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @PathParam("productName") String productName) throws IOException {
    File folderPath = new File("/Users/homeDirectory/Desktop/FileUploadTest");
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(folderPath+"/"+ file.getOriginalFilename());
    fout.write(file.getBytes());
    fout.close();
    return "Response";
```

I've another client(submodule) who is calling the upload endpoint using Unirest. File Type can be CSV or PNG

```
File f = new File("/Users/homeDirectory/Desktop/aggregateReport.csv");
    HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("http://localhost:8080/report-rest/report/v1/file/test123")
            .field("file", f).asString();
```

and at server side I see the following error:

```html
Apr 04, 2020 10:13:33 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils logMessageHandlerProblem
SEVERE: No message body reader has been found for class org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile, ContentType: multipart/form-data;boundary=1MbhkGkO-__me1XVpPXpsLEWcSMn4ltIz4
Apr 04, 2020 10:13:33 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1339)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:824)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:788)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:212)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
 at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:218)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
 at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You are mixing Spring MVC and JAX-RS. You are using JAX-RS (CXF implementation), but you are trying to use Spring MVC pieces (`@RequestParam` and `MultiparFile`). You need to look into the CXF documentation for how to use multipart.

Answer (score 3):

@Paul Thank you providing the right direction. Posting correct code here so other's to help

```
@POST
@Path("file/{productName}")
public Response uploadFile(MultipartBody multipartBody, @PathParam("productName") String productName) {
    List<Attachment> attachments = multipartBody.getAllAttachments();
    List<DataHandler> dataHandlers = attachments.stream().map(Attachment::getDataHandler).collect(Collectors.toList());
    dataHandlers.forEach(dataHandler -> {
        String fileName = dataHandler.getName();
        try {
            InputStream fileContentStream = dataHandler.getInputStream();
            if (Objects.isNull(fileContentStream)) {
                LOGGER.error("Null Stream received in request");
            } else {
                String directoryPath = fileUtil.createDirectoryToSaveFiles(uploadProperties.getSourceDirectoryLocation(), productName);
                File fileToWrite = fileUtil.createFileToWrite(directoryPath + File.separator + fileName);
                fileUtil.writeContentInFile(fileContentStream, fileToWrite);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong while writing to file "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    });
    return Response.ok("Sample String").build();
}
```

Comment: Saved a really hectic day..Thanks for the answer.